# Response Mapping in servlet

Tags: servlets, ember.js

How does response mapping work in a Servlet?

How does each response know to flush out the output on that particular HTML or handlebars?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once.

Comment: Your question is more confusing because you have an "ember.js" tag.  Do you realize that Ember is a SPA (Single Page Application) and there is no "flushing out" happening on the server?  The entire application with all compiled handlebar templates are sent with the first request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a [ember-java](https://github.com/brunorg/ember-java/blob/master/src/tomcat/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml) github projects with `Jersey REST Service`

It uses `com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer` which extends `HttpServlet`. it return the output using [ServletResponse](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/servletapi/javax/servlet/ServletResponse.html) which write the body and Calling `flush()`

> **getOutputStream** ..
>   Calling flush() on the ServletOutputStream commits the response. Either this method or getWriter() may be called to write the body

If you check specific service in servlet it returns json response (`@Produces`)

```
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Customers get(@QueryParam("ids[]") List<Long> ids) {
    if (ids != null && !ids.isEmpty()) {
        return new Customers(manager.findByIds(ids));
    }
    return new Customers(manager.findAll());
}
```

Ember is connection to HTTP Server using adapters

> The store uses an object called an adapter to know how to communicate over the network. By default, the store will use DS.RESTAdapter, an adapter that communicates with an HTTP server by transmitting JSON via XHR

[ember-data.js](https://github.com/brunorg/ember-java/blob/f7ad57fad3d2c65e572fd8f38ff22109ed5d205a/app/lib/vendor/ember-data.js) have the adapter configuration

```
DS.RESTAdapter = DS.Adapter.extend({ ...
```

It return Customers which is defined in [router.js](https://github.com/brunorg/ember-java/blob/f7ad57fad3d2c65e572fd8f38ff22109ed5d205a/app/lib/router.js)

> App.Router.map(function() {
>     this.resource("customers");
>     this.resource("customer", {
>       path: '/customer/:customer_id'
>     });

and have customer templates in [customer.hbs](https://github.com/brunorg/ember-java/blob/f7ad57fad3d2c65e572fd8f38ff22109ed5d205a/app/lib/templates/customer.hbs)